# QML - Unable to show javascript dialogs with WebView

Tags: qt, webview, qml, qt-quick

I have a simple QML code, and a simple HTML code with some javascript, and I cant figure out how to display the dialog in my javascript.

**Here is my QML code :**

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtWebKit 3.0

Rectangle {
    width: 1280
    height: 720
    color:"#ff000000"

    WebView {
            id: webView
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            anchors.fill: parent
            url: "index.html"
        }
}
```

**Here is my index.html code :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>index</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <button onclick="testAlert();">Button</button>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function testAlert()
            {
                alert("test");
            }
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

In a normal web browser, this html code is working and displaying me a dialog. In the QML WebView, the dialog is not showing.

Can somebody help me to find the problem ?
Thanks.